# Как реализовать подобный интерфейс в android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-tablayout

подскажите как можно реализовать подобный интерфейс вкладок c листами как в excel mobile? Прикинул что это можно реализовать с помощью tablayout с фрагментами, но как мне сделать чтобы была возможность редактировать текст вкладки, как показано на фото? Или это реализуется другими средствами? В каком направлении мне двигаться?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галку слева от него.

Answer (score 0):

Вам можно использовать [TableLayout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/grid). Для этого будет достаточно взять и в tableLayout добавить в качестве ячейки EditText. Вот пример работы с TextView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1">
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/table_layout_4_open"
            android:padding="3dip" />
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/table_layout_4_open_shortcut"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="3dip" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/table_layout_4_save"
            android:padding="3dip" />
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/table_layout_4_save_shortcut"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="3dip" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

и вот результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В вашем случае вы можете добавить поля для ввода и все. Дальше подключаете в активности например так -

```
setContentView(R.layout.main)
```

Вот например есть [туториал](https://abhiandroid.com/ui/tablelayout) как работать с данным видом виджета. Остается только вопрос в программной генерации дополнительных ячеек когда вы будете скроллить вашу таблицу. Для скрола можно добавить простой ScrollView который будет родительским элементом у TableView и потом при достижении одной из "граней" макета добавлять ячейки в TableView.